# How to do metaprogramming in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Doing SSIS after a long time.

I have several packages and each one is specific to a table and they all (most of them) are doing standard ETL - extract from one source, transform and load into a different source.

How can I convert this into one package and provide table names (source and destination) as input parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly. The way a Data Flow works is by tightly binding to the schema of the data from the source. Column names and data types can't change. By knowing in advance the widest a single row can be, the SSIS execution engine can then preallocate memory for rowwidth * BufferRowSize and know that all the data will fit in that address space and they can do their in-memory modifications to all that data.

The actual packages on disk must be bound to the source data shape. But, that doesn't mean you need to physically build all those packages. I don't and I do a wee bit of SSIS.

If you have a .NET mind, you can go with either the base API or you can try the [EzAPI](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) but that's more work than I generally want to do.

Instead, I use [Biml](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181965+biml). Think about a truncate and reload pattern with a flat file source. What does it look like? At a minimum, an Execute SQL Task, a Data Flow and two Connection Managers (Source and Destination). Great, so build that once and call it V1. Then you figure out what changes when you use a different source file and/or destination and that's the basis for V2. This is still a manual approach but now you know when I need a new source and destination, I make N changes to this file and click the button and out comes a package.

Once you get a feel for what needs to change to satisfy your design pattern, *then* automate the snot out of it. Biml is awesome because it allows you to use scripting, much as we did for classic ASP. It's a klunky scripting experience with the free version, BIDS Helper, but the paid-for-tool, Mist has a very slick experience. For example, look at my [Replicate-O-Matic](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/01/biml-replicate-o-matic.html) post. My target biml file takes a schema and table parameter and that's enough for me to generate a package that copies all the data from my source connection to the destination. That's a simple example. [mmarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514839/mmarie) has has a great pattern where her target has a dozen parameters that cover everything she needs for a fact load. She collects all the metadata she needs into a table and generates all of the SSIS to solve her data warehouse loads. Think about that, you shift the expertise required from knowing SSIS to collecting the right bits of metadata about the problem. You discover that Truncate and Reload is not appropriate but instead you need an Incremental load pattern, no problem. You invoke a different Biml file, preferably with the same parameters, and out comes a package that solves the same business problem but in a different fashion.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the direction. I am new to SSIS but have been a developer (ruby developer not .Net) for long time. I will start digging into those tools you recommended.

Comment: Do you know if BIML has all the functionality that SSIS components provide including lookup, logging, casting data types, foreach loop, sequence container, event handler etc. Related question, would you recommend using BIML for all these operations?

Comment: Anything you do in the SSIS designer, you can do with Biml. Look through the supplied answers where I've mentioned Biml and then ask yourself how you would make them metadata driven. I've build packages by hand, using the SSIS libraries, using the EzAPI wrapper and now I'm using Biml. For me, using Biml has saved me man-weeks of development time in the almost two years I've been using it. If technology X comes out that is more efficient than Biml for solving business intelligence problems, I'll hop on that bandwagon. Until then though, you'll pry my Biml from my sweaty, carpal tunneled hands